# Push Notification Django 1.9

Tags: django, api, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, django-rest-framework

I am working on the project which is already developed in **Django 1.9**.
I have searched a lot and not find any compatible version of Library to implement the push notification Via Django DRF and Firebase (FCM).

Can anyone help me to suggest a Push notification library that can I implement for my project.

**Following are the libraries that I had searched and not working either with python3 or with django 1.9**

1. https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications
2. https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm

Just need suggestion to pick stable library to send push notification via Django Rest Frameworkd(DRF) using Firebase.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: RestFrameWork is '3.6.3'

Answer (score 0):

Look at [pyfcm](https://github.com/olucurious/pyfcm). This library looks promising for me and works best for FCM push notifications. Documentation includes each example for your needs.

Note : This library has nothing to do with any web framework. It can be implemented anywhere as it can be implemented in python itself.

Here's minimal example for sending push notification to multiple devices,

```
# Send to single device.
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>")
# Send to multiple devices by passing a list of ids.
registration_ids = ["<device registration_id 1>", "<device registration_id 2>", ...]
message_title = "title"
message_body = "Dev loves Stack overflow"
result = push_service.notify_multiple_devices(registration_ids=registration_ids, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)
```